# I'm trying to factory reset my phone but...?

Tags: factory-reset

...when it reaches the point where it asks to confirm my PIN, an error message saying "Unfortunately, Android keyboard (AOSP) has stopped". So i'm unable to type my pin in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing keyboard, go to the Play Store, download a keyboard, then go to settings and activate it and then you should be able to enter the pin

Answer (score 0):

Goto Play store and download Swift keyboard. Now you should be able to reset it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the below steps on your device. These steps may vary slightly based on the Android version you use but it may  be similar in the settings(i.e. menu option may change ).

1.Open up the menu.

2.navigate to Settings.

3.open Apps>All.

4.Scroll to the app Android keyboard (AOSP).

5.Then choose Clear data option.

6.Scroll to the User dictionary and do a simple force stop

This is just a small bug in the Android Keyboard.
Note:-By doing these steps you will lose all the typed/saved words in the dictionary which you have entered apart from the standard words which remain the same.